# Roundoff Errors: The Sum

Tags: c, math, floating-point

I have an university powerpoint slide claiming that doing the sum of a succession like

1 / i^2

With the index "i" from 0 to 2260, is different than doing the sum of the same numbers but starting from the most big to the most little (from 1/ 2260^2 to 1/0^2).

Trying to do this on C, I have these results:

```
Increasing Order Sum: 1.644491e+00.
Decreasing Order Sum: 1.644491e+00.
Relative Error (abs(Incr. Sum - Decr. Sum) / abs(Incr. Sum)) : 2.700465e-15.
```

Could someone explain me why this happens? I have no solutions on these slides.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I hope 1/(0^2) isn't actually in either sum.

Comment: I assume the `^` in the slide means `pow` and not bit-xor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because floating-point addition is not [associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative), in general.  In other words, `(a + b) + c` is not necessarily the same as `a + (b + c)`.

To see why, try running this code:

```
float a = 1e9;
float b = 1;
a += b;
printf("%f\n", a);
```

Then consider what happens if you add `b` to `a` 1 million times.  And then consider what would happen if you swapped the operations (i.e. add 1e9 last).

Comment: "Because floating-point addition is not associative" - so well said.  +1 from me.